# Working with a core data database

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am working with a core data database. So far I got it working that it's fetching all my data from a webservice an put it into an core data database. For that I am doing the following.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if (!self.genkDatabase) {  // we'll create a default database if none is set
        NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
        url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Default appGenk Database"];
        self.genkDatabase = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url]; // setter will create this for us on disk
    }
}
- (void)fetchGenkDataIntoDocument:(UIManagedDocument *)document
{
    NSLog(@"Fetch data");
    dispatch_queue_t fetchQ = dispatch_queue_create("Genk fetcher", NULL);
    dispatch_async(fetchQ, ^{
        NSArray *news       = [GenkData getNews];
        NSArray *players    = [GenkData getPlayers];
        NSArray *staff      = [GenkData getStaff];
        NSArray *trainingen = [GenkData getTrainingen];

        [document.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{ // perform in the NSMOC's safe thread (main thread)
            for (NSDictionary *genkInfo in news) {
               [News newsWithGenkInfo:genkInfo inManagedObjectContext:document.managedObjectContext];
                // table will automatically update due to NSFetchedResultsController's observing of the NSMOC
            }
            for (NSDictionary *genkInfo in staff) {
                [Staff staffWithGenkInfo:genkInfo inManagedObjectContext:document.managedObjectContext];
                // table will automatically update due to NSFetchedResultsController's observing of the NSMOC
            }
            for (NSDictionary *genkInfo in players) {
                [Team teamWithGenkInfo:genkInfo inManagedObjectContext:document.managedObjectContext];
                // table will automatically update due to NSFetchedResultsController's observing of the NSMOC
            }
            for (NSDictionary *genkInfo in trainingen ) {
                [Training trainingWithGenkInfo:genkInfo inManagedObjectContext:document.managedObjectContext];

            }
            [document saveToURL:document.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting completionHandler:NULL];
            // note that we don't do anything in the completion handler this time
        }];
    });
}
- (void)setGenkDatabase:(UIManagedDocument *)genkDatabase
{
    if (_genkDatabase != genkDatabase) {
        _genkDatabase = genkDatabase;
        [self useDocument];
    }
}
- (void)useDocument
{
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self.genkDatabase.fileURL path]]) {
        // does not exist on disk, so create it
        [self.genkDatabase saveToURL:self.genkDatabase.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {

            [self setupFetchedResultsController];
            [self fetchGenkDataIntoDocument:self.genkDatabase];

        }];
    } else if (self.genkDatabase.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
        // exists on disk, but we need to open it
        [self.genkDatabase openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            [self setupFetchedResultsController];
        }];
    } else if (self.genkDatabase.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal) {
        // already open and ready to use
        [self setupFetchedResultsController];
    }

}

- (void)setupFetchedResultsController // attaches an NSFetchRequest to this UITableViewController
{

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"News"];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO]];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                        managedObjectContext:self.genkDatabase.managedObjectContext
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];

}
```

I am doing al this on the first viewController that opens.
My question is know how can i get to the core data database without every time implement these methods in my view controller? Because when I want to execute a fetch request I need a managedobject context.  And for now I only can get it by the following

self.genkDatabase.managedObjectContext

Please help
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is one way I can think of. You can create the managedObjectContext property in AppDelegate which is going to be shared across the app. If you create a new project in Xcode and (select master-Detail application) and check the option to "Use core data" while creating it. Xcode will generate all the code required automatically and also will create a managedObjectContext Property.

And you can get the context anywhere in the app by using,

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
```

Answer (score 0):

if I were you, I would use a singletone Object(e.g FetchDataHandler) and ObjectDelegate to handle this.

```
1.So you don't need to keep repeating the code.
```

Instead of putting the code in the view controller, put it in this object, and provide methods.

```
- (void)fetchDataFrom:(NSURL *)_url
```

and for delegate

```
- (void)fetchDataHandler:(FetchDataHandler *) _handler didFinishFetchingData:(XXXXX *) _XXXX
```

where XXXX is what you get back from the URL.

According to you code, replace

```
[self setupFetchedResultsController];
```

to

```
[self.delegate fetchDataHandler:self didFinishFetchingData:self.data];
```

so, you may start you fetching using 'fetchDataFrom', and when it finish 'didFinishFetchingData' will be called.

the main idea is to seperate backend code and front end code.

comment if i am wrong.